# How init some data from datastore before start app (setContent) jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How init data (from datastore) before start app (setContent) in jetpack compose?

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            AdaptatorTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    MainScreen(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Android Splash screen library to hold the display of the app until you have loaded the data you need.

See [this document](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#suspend-drawing) for reference, but the gist is here

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Set the layout for the content view.
    setContent {
        if (viewModel.isReady) {
            // your app content here
        }
    }

    // Set up an OnPreDrawListener to the root view.
    val content: View = findViewById(android.R.id.content)
    content.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(
        object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                // Check whether the initial data is ready.
                return if (viewModel.isReady) {
                    // The content is ready.
                    content.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                    true
                } else {
                    // The content isn't ready. Suspend.
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking about splash... Вut it about cover, not upload init

Comment: The only way you could load data before setContent would be to use runBlocking, but that's not recommended, you would freeze the UI while the data loads.